# How can I check that a variable is in a table using sqlite through python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

What sql query can be used to search for a variable in a table, with the aim that the variable isn't there. How do I know if a value is in my table? Because I haven't found a search query yet.

I tried making the sql query a varible and setting it to true/false but that didn't work.

I created the table in sqlite it has the following fields ('CustomerID', 'UserName', 'FirstName', 'Password', 'Email') . I'm doing validation and I want to check if a username has already been used.

Comment: Better start by showing us the CREATE for your table so we know what the data looks like.  Also include an example of the data in the table you'd like to search for.

Comment: I created the table in sqlite it has the following fields ('CustomerID', 'UserName', 'FirstName', 'Password', 'Email') . I'm doing validation and I want to check if a username has already been used.

Comment: @Megan59781 Please do not put relevant information in the comments, but edit your question instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a SQL check something like...

```
SELECT 1 AS userExists
  FROM yourTable
 WHERE userName = 'JoeBloggs'
 LIMIT 1
```

*(Return the value 1 for each row where the username is JoeBloggs, but limit the results to just one row.)*

Then, in the python, check how many rows it returns.  `0` rows = it doesn't exist, `1` row = it exists at least once.